# Cannot find module

Tags: reactjs, module, react-hooks, node-modules, package.json

I got this error when i ran my code, what can i do? i have deleted node modules and reinstalled it yet, the error is still there.
N/B: I am using react for my project.

Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/Components/Pages/Home/home.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[0].oneOf[5].use[2]!./src/Components/Pages/Home/home.css) 5:36-97

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../images//my-recharge-banner.png' in 'C:\Users\HI\Desktop\my-recharge\my-recharge-web-services\src\Components\Pages\Home'

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: usually one gets the error like yours when he/she tries to run the project out of file path) to be clear, your node modules files may be `C\myComputer\myproject\main` path, but you are trying to run the project `C\myComputer\myproject` path. Check your pth

Comment: thank you @MukhriddinShakhriyorov , i cut out the image folder and placed it inside the pages folder, the error disappeared.